# AngularJS Scope Update Requires Double Button Click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Controller:

```
// Modal Controller
app.controller("ModalCtrl", ["$scope", "$filter", function($scope, $filter) {

  var date = new Date();
  var currentDate = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'MM/dd/yyyy');

  // Form Submit Actions
  $scope.submitFormCreateAccount = function() {
    $('#form-create-account').form('submit');
  };
  $scope.submitFormSignIn = function() {
    $('#form-sign-in').form('submit');
  };

  // Form Validation - Create Account
  $('#form-create-account').form({
      on: 'blur',
      fields: {
          email: {
              identifier: 'email',
              rules: [{
                  type: 'email',
                  prompt: 'Please enter a valid email address.'
              }]
          },
          displayName: {
              identifier: 'displayName',
              rules: [{
                  type: 'empty',
                  prompt: 'Please enter a display name for yourself.'
              }]
          },
          password: {
            identifier: 'password',
            rules: [{
              type: 'empty',
              prompt: 'Please enter a password'
            },{
              type: 'length[6]',
              prompt: 'Password needs to be atleast 6 characters long'
            }]
          },
          passwordConfirm: {
            identifier: 'passwordConfirm',
            rules: [{
              type: 'match[password]',
              prompt: 'Password don\'t match'
            }]
          }
      },
      onSuccess: function() {
        createUser();
        return false;
      },
      onFailure: function() {

        return false;
      }
  });
  // Form Validation - Sign In
  $('#form-sign-in').form({
      on: 'blur',
      fields: {
          email: {
              identifier: 'emailSignIn',
              rules: [{
                  type: 'email',
                  prompt: 'Please enter a valid email address.'
              }]
          },
          password: {
              identifier: 'passwordSignIn',
              rules: [{
                type   : 'empty',
                prompt : 'Please enter a password.'
              }]
          }
      },
      onSuccess: function() {
        signInUser();
        return false;
      },
      onFailure: function() {
        // Fail Function
        return false;
      }
  });

  // Create User
  function createUser() {
    email = $scope.createUserEmail;
    displayName = $scope.createUserDisplayName;
    password = $scope.createUserPassword;

    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(function(firebaseUser) {
        userId = firebaseUser.uid;

        // Add user to RealtimeDB
        database.ref('users/' + userId).set({
          name: displayName,
          email: email,
          added: currentDate
        });

        $('.ui.modal').modal("hide");
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        $scope.modalErrorMessage = true;
        $scope.errorMessage = error;
      });
  };

  // Sign In User
  function signInUser() {
    email = $scope.signInUserEmail;
    password = $scope.signInUserPassword;

    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(value) {
      $('.ui.modal').modal("hide");
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;

      if (errorCode == 'auth/invalid-email') {
        console.log(errorMessage);
        $scope.modalErrorMessage = true;
        $scope.errorMessage = errorMessage;
      } else {
        console.log(errorMessage);
        $scope.modalErrorMessage = true;
        $scope.errorMessage = errorMessage;
      }
    });
  }

  // Sign Out User
  $scope.signOutUser = function() {
    auth.signOut().then(function() {

    }, function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}]);
```

View:

```
<div class="ui warning message modal-message"
         ng-show="modalErrorMessage">
      <div class="header">
        Whoops!
      </div>
      <p>{{errorMessage}}</p>
    </div>
```

Everything works fine, but when the createUser() or signInUser() functions run, this bit doesn't run unless the mentioned functions are activated twice:

```
}).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        $scope.modalErrorMessage = true;
        $scope.errorMessage = error;
      });
```

For reference, the two functions are run from a button click (if the form is valid).  How do I make it so that the error bits run on the initial click instead of having to run the function twice?

Comment: The catch method will only be executed if your api call fails. You need to check if you api is failing the second time.

Comment: It does, and it's supposed to.  The console.log(error) runs on the first button click, but the two lines after that (the $scope's) only run on the second button click.  Why isn't the $scope updating on the first click?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by wrapping the $scope updates in a timeout() function.